# TWebUpdate E2003 Undeclared identifier _WIN32_FIND_DATA

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I am trying to install TMS `TWebUpdate` in Delphi 11.1 using the last version I have, which installs fine in Berlin and Tokyo. Alas, it Alexandria it gives an error

> [dcc32 Error] wupdate.pas(2342): E2003 Undeclared identifier: '_WIN32_FIND_DATA'

TMS no longer provides `TWebUpdate` as a standalone component, and I cannot afford £320 for the VCL Pack it is now part of!

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously, there was a

```
_WIN32_FIND_DATA
```

which was an alias for

```
_WIN32_FIND_DATAW
```

Now, Embarcadero has decided not to include such aliases any more, so you need to append the `W` yourself.

(Of course, there's also a `_WIN32_FIND_DATAA`, but today we only need the wide version.)

Alternatively, you can use `WIN32_FIND_DATA` or `WIN32_FIND_DATAW` or the more Delphi-like `TWin32FindData` (or `TWin32FindDataW`). These are all the same thing.

Comment: Wow what a fast response! Well implemented the 'W' and at least it compiles fine. Now to get it to install!
Many thanks!

Comment: Well I got it installed and working in 10.4 but 11.1 doesn't seem to like it! Never-mind, will keep at it or stick with 10.4

Comment: OK, so got it installed in 11.1, no idea why it kept erroring but eventually it in, and works a treat!

Comment: "*Alternatively, you can use `WIN32_FIND_DATA` ... or the more Delphi-like `TWin32FindData`...*" - +1